# Convex planar curves and intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Given two planar regular convex not-closed curves C and C_1.
Let A the set of finite intersections between C and C-1.
Then what is the stricter upper bound of |A|?

I would say 2. 
Thanks.

Comment: Viewed from the Sun, the orbits of both Earth and Moon are convex, yet they cross each other about 25 times a year.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That's a cool fact that the orbit of the Moon is convex!

Comment: I'd be amazed if ellipses weren't considered "regular". But even ellipses intersect as many as 4 times. See also Bezout's theorem.

Comment: http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/teaching/convex.html, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266426/what-does-the-moons-orbit-around-the-sun-look-like, http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10979/moons-orbit-around-the-sun, http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1912JRASC...6..117T

Comment: I think I understand what the OP is asking: whether two _non-compact_ convex algebraic curves in $\mathbf P^2$ can intersect in more than 2 points. I'm not sure that any of the existing comments and answers (e.g. referring to ellipses, or taking non-closed segments of curves) answer this. But of course the answer is still yes.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the edit - a curve should be of class C^2 to have an everywhere-defined curvature.

Comment: It's a bad idea to change the question so much that an answer already given changes from relevant to irrelevant. Better would be to open a new question entirely.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Yes I agree with you. I thought that the new question would have been posted  as a fresh question.  I think I have misunderstood the following fact: My question has been considered off topic but it has been answered.  For sure it is my fault. My apologies.

Comment: Francesco, thanks for explaining. I think what I'll do is roll back to the previous version, and then if you'd like to start a new thread and ask a different question, go right ahead. (However, my suspicion is that part of the question you mean to ask would not get a good reception here, because the basic picture given by Joseph O'Rourke is robust and could be easily modified to get strict convexity, i.e., the question would not be considered "research level" (for mathematicians). Maybe Mathematics StackExchange would be the better site for this type of question.)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know if that picture is so robust against my question. I mean the nice counterexample is based on the fact that there are pieces of the curves with a curvature is equal to 0. In the extreme case, two straight lines (curvature 0) can meet for sure infinite times. For sure I was very imprecise in posting the first question that is appearing now. I don't think that the second question is totally trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Could you clarify what is a "regular convex curve"?
For if appropriate rounding of the corners of a convex polygon leaves it regular, then there is no upper bound.

---

[image: Dodecagons]

---